# Listen to file updates in MAC & iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, file, listener

I would like to ask if there is any way to listen in concrete folders if any file has been created or updated in MAC or iOS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.macworld.com/article/1046516/filesystemusage.html

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent example on http://developer.apple.com - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052.

Look at the DirectoryWatcher in particular. You can monitor a whole directory with it and it notifies you if any changes to the files in that directory were made.